# Stop Outlook 2007 from creating tasks for everything starred in Gmail?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, gmail-imap

I'm using Outlook 2007 to connect to my GMail account through IMAP.  Unfortunately this creates a flagged item and an task entry for every *starred* item in GMail.

[How to geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/prevent-outlook-with-gmail-imap-from-showing-duplicate-tasks-in-the-to-do-bar/) shows how to make this work properly (only show each item once) but doesn't show how to stop it altogether?

How can I stop this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You should try](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=5b52c8fbc89d47ce&hl=en) unsubscribing from the Starred and All Mail folders.

Unsubscribe by right clicking on your IMAP folder and select IMAP folders, then click Query and select the two and click Unsubscribe

[image]

Comment: Let's hope this one works!

Comment: Even if it doesn't its something cool I didn't know!

Comment: I learned to use this to filter out downloading Support mails from our company Inbox :P